# I am getting "Signature for this request is not valid" in binance API for batchOrders (/fapi/v1/batchOrders)

Tags: node.js, binance

I am creating batch Orders in the following way : and I am getting Signature for this request is not valid , any Idea what is going wrong? Thank you

`

```
const axios = require('axios')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const apiKey = ''
const apiSecret = ''

const baseUrl = 'https://testnet.binancefuture.com'
const endpoint = '/fapi/v1/batchOrders'

const orders = [
    {
        symbol: 'BTCUSDT',
        side: 'BUY',
        type: 'MARKET',
        quantity: '0.01'
    },
    {
        symbol: 'ETHUSDT',
        side: 'SELL',
        type: 'STOP_MARKET',
        quantity: '0.1',
        stopPrice: '4000'
    }
]

const timestamp = Date.now()  
const recvWindow = 5000

const query =      `batchOrders=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(orders))}&timestamp=${timestamp}&recvWindow=${recvWindow}`
const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(query).digest('hex')

console.log(signature);

const headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Accept-Encoding":"*"
}


console.log("URL")
console.log(baseUrl + endpoint + '?' + query + '&signature=' + signature);


axios.post(baseUrl + endpoint + '?' + query + '&signature=' + signature, {}, { headers: headers })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
         console.error(err.response.data)
    })
```

`

I am getting Signature for this request is not valid when I run the code, I am not sure if I am doing any thing wrong, is there anything that i am doing wrong here? This is the result I am getting:

{ code: -1022, msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.' }